# Argument 1: cannot convert from System.IO.FileInfo to 'string'

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FunkcjaSpilit
{

    class Program2
    {

        static int _MinWordLength = 7;
        static void Main()
        {
            DirectoryInfo filePaths = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\project_IAD");
            FileInfo[] Files = filePaths.GetFiles("*.sgm");
            List<string> firstone = new List<string>();



            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                int longWordsCount = CalculateLongWordsCount(file, _MinWordLength);

                Console.WriteLine("W tekscie numer: " + firstone.IndexOf(file) + " liczba długich słów to " + longWordsCount);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int CalculateLongWordsCount(FileInfo file, int minWordLength)
        {
            return file.Split(' ').Where(wordInText => wordInText.Length >= minWordLength).Count();
        }

    }
}
```

After runing this code an error occurs:
**(local variable) FileInfo file
CS 1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from System.IO.FileInfo to 'string'**
How it can be fixed?

Comment: `file.Split(' ')` => `f.FullName.Split(' ')` or `f.Name.Split(' ')`. Or you can use directly `Directory.GetFiles()` that returns a `string[]`

Comment: thx, it help for line with "Split", but "file" issue in 25 line still occurs.

Comment: What do you think the `FileInfo file` variable contains? Hint: it's **NOT** just the file name. It's also **NOT** the contents of the file.

Comment: What is "line 25"? Where does the error happens, exactly?

Comment: @Alejandro I believe it's the `Console.WriteLine()` statement. That is the other place the FileInfo is used incorrectly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, exactly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems in the code. Both of them come from not understanding what the `FileInfo` struct is for. I'll fix one of the errors, and leave you to learn from my fix to do the second yourself.

```
private static int CalculateLongWordsCount(FileInfo file, int minWordLength)
{
    return File.ReadLines(file.FullName).
        Select(line => line.Split(' ').Count(word => word.Length > minWordLength)).
        Sum();
}
```

You could also use `File.ReadAllText()` for this and it would be simpler and more closely resemble the original code, but I prefer `ReadLines()` for giving at least some protection against large files blowing up your memory.

The other problem is in this expression:

```
firstone.IndexOf(file)
```

But, again, I leave this to you to fix, so that you will be sure to understand how to use the `FileInfo` struct. Separate from the `FileInfo` problem, this expression will also **always** return `-1`, because no data is ever added to the `firstone` list.

Comment: Thx you very much)